# Use AngularJS Variable, where another AngularJS Variable matches its ID

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` statement where I want to show an image. The image however, should be chosen from where the ng-repeat's ID matches the image object's ID.

I am unsure of how to do this properly, here is psuedo code of what I am trying to do.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in rosterData | orderBy:'name'">
   <img ng-src="{{champion.imagename WHERE user.id = champion.id}} />
</tr>
```

Remember that `champion.id` is an object of champions, so I want to make sure I get the right `champion.name` to match with the right `champion.id` when it matches the current ng-repeat `user.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could check those logic inside the controller:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in rosterData | orderBy:'name'">
   <img ng-src="{{getImage(user.id)}} />
</tr>
```

In your controller:

```
    $scope.getImage = function(userId) {
       var image = "defaultimage";
       $scope.champions.forEach(function(champion) {
         if(champion.id===userId) {
               image = champion.image;
         } 
      });
      return image;
   }
```

Comment: Will this work since `if(userId===$scope.champion.id)` is an array of champion objects? Do I need to iterate through it or can I just get the champion object where that championObject.id = the userid? The id will exist, I just need to match it to the right champion, then return that champions name.

Comment: Oh, if champion is an array then use `$scope.champion.some(function(val){return val.id===userId})` and based on return statement show the image

Comment: How does it know which scope.champion.image it is returning?

Comment: cool so this works, BUT my console blows up at me now. :S `Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: ./Content/Champions/{{getImage(u.champion1)}}.png
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` Any way to make Angular happy and not hate me? Could it be that my champion array hasn't injected in time? Can I delay the method from firing at all?

Comment: Whether champions is not defined in this controller?

Comment: They are defined, the images all work now! But my console gives me errors (even though it works/runs). Are those errors okay, if the program works?

Comment: I wrapped my $scope.getImage in a $timeout, is that an okay way to handle this? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Using $timeout is an hack. Let me check and help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73999/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-austin).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put a method in "ng-src" statement, pass the id as a parameter - > iterate array, find match and so on.

Method should be added in controller to $scope property, than just call  it :)

Comment: I've mentioned it in my answer @Marcus

Comment: I was writing my answer when you added post and your solution doesnt include iteration